# Categories are not available AT ALL under Menus

Tags: categories, menus, cache

I installed and activated Envo Shop for my new WordPress website which is hosted on **Hostinger**. Everything almost is going good except, Categories which are not showing up under Appearance, Menus.
Currently, there are 12 available Categories (including **Uncategorized** category). All other Categories have at least one product but Uncategorized doesn't include any product!
Now I created new Menu only for available categories, I see nothing except Uncategorized!!!
I also **Purged All** caches from WordPress itself and from Browser but it still doesn't work.
I have done some researches to find out proper solution for this problem but most of similar problems are related to specific Menu plugins while I use no plugin for Menus. **Only Woocommerce**
**What is the problem? Why there are no categories under my new menu?**
I attached two images of current problem down below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first screenshot is Product Categories. Your second screenshot is just Categories. These are not the same thing. On the Menu page open _Screen Options_ and make sure Product Categories is checked.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for your help yes it's now available I mistook Categories with Product Categories.